# Binding $scope variable value with formData angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to submit the form.I am using ng-submit.After clicking a particular user inside table i am calling modal popup with firstName.
Here is the code for html.

```
    <form ng-submit="submitPunch()"  class="form" ng-show="true"> 
    <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-
    hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Employee Punch In</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 form-group mgl15">
            <label for="type">Employee</label><br>
            <input type="hidden" ng-model="formData.employeeId">
            {{firstName}} /* Here i want to show only firstName but i want to pass corresponding id of the employee with formData */
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 form-group mgl15">
            <label for="PIN">{{'label.Enter_Pin'|i18next}} <span
            class="text-red">*</span></label>
            <input class="form-control" id="pin" ng-model="formData.pin"
            type="text" required>
        </div>
       </div>
  </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-
       dismiss="modal">Close</button>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-
       disabled="submitStatus==='success'">Submit</button>
       </div>
       </form>
```

Here is how i am passing firstName to modal

Controller.js

```
    $scope.testpopup = function(employee){
            $scope.firstName = employee.firstName;
            $scope.employeeId=employee.id;
            console.log($scope.employeeId);//Here i am getting id
            $(".testmodal").modal("show");
        }
```

Now i want to send employee id along with pin.But if i bind employeeId with formData it is not taking.I want to pass id along with pin for saving.Can anyone tell how to bind id with formData?If i put console($scope.formData) it is showing only pin entered but not employee id.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a fiddle that I've made.](https://jsfiddle.net/Canet/uk7xpv1e/2/)

```
$scope.testpopup = function(employee){
    $(".modal").modal("show");
    $scope.selectedEmployee = employee;
}
```

If this does not match with your intent, please give me feedback.

But I recommend you to use [uib-modal.](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

.

.

.

**UPDATE**

[Another fiddle is here.](https://jsfiddle.net/Canet/uk7xpv1e/5/)

Is this more close with your purpose?

Comment: I want to bind it with form data.